# How to get body of get request?

Tags: php, get

I'm aware of the [specifics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) of params usage in get http request body. However, just looking for a way how to grab body of get http request.

Comment: GET requests don't have a body.

Comment: `Body of GET request`?? Can you make it more clear?

Comment: This has "bad idea" written all over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get requests per the spec do not have a body but if they did `file_get_contents("php://input");` would be your best bet

Comment: does a webserver need some configuration, or this just works out of the box?

Comment: Works out of the box AFAIK. What makes you believe you are getting a body in the request?